# nested annotations django with OuterRef

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I want to annotate a field based on another queryset.

```
 return real_instances.annotate(        
  submitted_count=user_enrolments.filter(course_progresses__module_progresses__module__id=OuterRef('id')).annotate(
            submitted_attempt=Exists(
                AssignmentModuleProgress.objects
                .filter(
                    Q(module_progress__module__id=OuterRef(OuterRef('id')))
                    Q(module_progress__user=OuterRef('user')) &
                    Q(module_progress__module_progress_course_progresses__course_progress_userenrolments__id=OuterRef("id")),
                    is_submitted=True)
            )).filter(submitted_attempt=True).count(),
```

Here i have a QuerySet by the name real_instances and i want to annotate a field submitted_count in it . user_enrolments is another queryset and im annotating another field in it by the name submitted_attemmpt to finally get my count . Here im having issue with OuterRef(OuterRef('pk')) which refers to the id of the real_instances object in iteration. Im getting the error:

```
ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```